# I want to find the unique count but getting the error while using the length (unique()) in rstudio

Tags: r

I am using the query :

```
aggregate(t3$Tenant.Id, by = t3[c("Cb.Plan.Id" ,"Plan.Id")], length)
```

getting the result as :

[image]

but i want the tenant id as unique values or distinct values.
tried with code:

```
aggregate(t3$Tenant.Id, by = t3[c("Cb.Plan.Id" ,"Plan.Id")], 
length(unique(Tenant.Id)))
```

error message was in image

Comment: Show your input dataframe

Answer (score 0):

We can use anonymous function to do this with a `formula` method

```
aggregate(Tenant.Id ~ Cb.Plan.Id + Plan.ID ~ t3, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Or change the `length` to anonymous function in the OP's code

```
aggregate(t3$Tenant.Id, by = t3[c("Cb.Plan.Id" ,"Plan.Id")],
      FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Comment: thanks for the fast response and getting the error with above code: "Error in model.frame.default(formula = Tenant.Id ~ Cb.Plan.Id + Plan.ID ~  : 
  object is not a matrix"

Comment: @SaiSaranGangisetty  Can you try `aggregate(t3$Tenant.Id, by = t3[c("Cb.Plan.Id" ,"Plan.Id")],
      FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))`

Comment: excellent ,  it worked..thanks and can i add the extra column as percentage of each result to the total users count..how can i add?

Comment: @SaiSaranGangisetty  YOu can do `do.call(data.frame, aggregate(t3$Tenant.Id, by = t3[c("Cb.Plan.Id" ,"Plan.Id")], FUN = function(x) c(length(unique(x)), length(x)/nrow(t3)))`

Comment: @getting error akrun..thanks for the help and i will add the %as seperate table with the master data

Comment: @Sai There might be a comma or something missing.  Please check